# What are good resources for Photographer's Rights around the world?

Tags: legal, travel

As a photographer, I take a lot of pictures around the world. In the US, the rights for photographers are pretty clear cut, although harassment and bullying occur at the hands of security and law enforcement personnel. However, the rights for photographers in other countries are not always so clear.

What are some good resources for photographer's rights for around the world?

Comment: For those in the US, there is a [nice summary of photographers' rights from the ACLU](http://www.aclu.org/free-speech/know-your-rights-photographers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For UK, some info can be found at website of [I'm a Photographer, not a Terrorist](http://photographernotaterrorist.org/) group, including a ["bust card"](http://photographernotaterrorist.org/bust-card/) which sums up your rights under [British Terrorism Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorism_Act_2000).

Other than that, I can only comment on the situation in the [Czech Republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_Republic), which seems to be pretty relaxed and free of any silly restrictions.

Answer (score 5):

For the US, Bert P. Krages, an Attorney, has a great write up about the [US Photographers Bill or Rights](http://www.krages.com/phoright.htm), which I recommend every US photographer print and carry with them.