# What is the philosophical justification generally accepted by photographers on why they should be able to profit privately over public property?

Tags: legal, copyright, philosophy

Say someone takes a picture of Lord Nelson's statue in Trafalgar Square at dusk, and sells on his website for profit.   Is it not arguable that people would not buy it if it weren't a statue of a famous historical figure, and thus the end product is as indelibly formed of public property as it is of the photographer's technical skill?  A more apt example, perhaps, would be that of a paparazzo snapping a picture of a famous celebrity in scandal — why should  the celebrity not have coequal rights as the photographer to profit off of or restrict the copyright of an image that  relies on his person to be attractive?  So my question is: What philosophical justifications have photographers generally accepted or promulgated to rebut these arguments?

N.B. To be clear, I'm not hostile towards photography or photographers; I just thought of this argument, and the resolution to it wasn't quite clear to me.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/does-a-photographer-take-pictures-or-make-pictures

Comment: My title's kind of a tongue-twister...neat.

Comment: As an aside, if it really were a photo taken in Trafalgar Square, then the photographer would legally have had to pay a (hefty) fee for a permit.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4140/21

Comment: Come to think of it, In a similar vein: Why should I have to pay for water; after all, it just falls out of the sky...

Comment: @Rowland Shaw I don't think your analogy is fair; what I'm really wondering is not that photographers profit, as a water company might from delivering water to our homes, but that they profit exclusively from pictures taken in public spaces -- if I'm not mistaken, water companies have to buy water rights from governments and individuals to mark up that water.  Why don't _papparazzi_ and street photographers have to buy personality rights from their subjects?

Comment: As it happens, you can't sell a photo taken in Trafalgar Square without paying the Greater London Authority a hefty sum. Same goes for Parliament Square and the Royal Parks. Just saying... :)

Comment: Are public _figures_ public property?

Comment: @billare: Perhaps you may be interested in reading Lawrence Lessig's Free Culture, which while not specific to photography is an extensive analysis of the considerations behind intellectual property: http://www.free-culture.cc/

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt I haven't read Lessig, but I've read enough of [Yochai Benkler's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yochai_Benkler) discussions of his work to have a good clue what he says in the book.   Where my confusion lies is it that photographers don't seem like Lessig's "free culture" people; they are quite exacting over intellectual property concerns with regard to their own "objects", their work, but I feel they are more dismissive of the property rights of the subjects they take photos of; one might imagine there'd be more of a symmetry.

Comment: (cont'd) Anyway, what I was hoping that  was that since obviously I can't be the first one to have thought of such an argument, that perhaps someone might give me a reference to a great photographer or photography guru who had written on such philosophical and legal thickets as these.

Comment: There's a couple more "see alsos" that are relevant here. Particularly, this question on model releases: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5031/is-a-model-release-needed-for-all-commercial-photo-sales, and this one on property releases: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10601/has-there-ever-been-a-ruling-on-the-necessity-legality-of-a-property-release-fo.

Comment: And, an off-site background article worth reading: Wikipedia on "Personality rights": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_rights

Comment: I hate to make your tongue-twister title even longer, but I'm afraid it really should be expanded to include people and property separately, since they're really two different, related issues.

Comment: @mattdm My title was near too long as it was, and I'm afraid editing it to include that bit has made it come off more hostile than I really intend it to be...

Comment: Well, maybe it's really two questions.... (Not saying it has to be, but maybe that's a way to untangle the issue a bit.)

Comment: @mattdm Perhaps you should take the lead in creating that question? I don't want to exhaust my goodwill with you folks by asking two "softish" type questions in a row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short and simple answer is that a photograph is a form of expression. I'm free to express myself as long as I don't infringe on somebody else's rights in doing so.

In the case of something like street photography, that usually works out fairly simply: if I take a picture in a place where somebody has a reasonable expectation of privacy, then I'm infringing on their rights, and I can't do it (without their permission). If they're in a place where they don't have a right to privacy, then I'm not infringing on their rights.

Looking at it from the other direction, going into a public place gives implicit consent to be watched, talked about, written about, videotaped, photographed, etc. If somebody prefers not to give the consent implicit with going into public, that's fine -- they're welcome to stay in a private place as long as they wish. When/if they choose to go into public, they have given up any right to privacy, and others' right to freedom of expression becomes the controlling factor, and a photograph is no different from any other form of expression.

Giving the subject of the speech, writing, photograph, videotape, etc., control over the results would infringe on the freedom of expression of the speaker/writer/photographer. The mere fact that they are the subject of the expression in question does not give them a right to limit or infringe on others' freedom of expression. Attempting to grant them such a right would utterly destroy freedom of speech/expression.

From a philosophical viewpoint, I see little difference between publishing a photograph of something "scandalous", or writing about the same subject. If we allow the subject to control that, it's a short, slippery slope to "you can't gossip about me", and even "you can't think nasty thoughts about me."

Edit: As @JoanneC pointed out, there are limits on the loss of privacy implicit in going out in public. In particular, what I *make* public becomes public, and what I keep private remains private. There mere act of walking out my door does not, of course, give anybody the right to look in my bank account, remove my clothes so they can take pictures of me naked (not that anybody would want to in my case!), break into my house to see what videos I like to watch, etc.

Comment: +1 I would tend to agree except they haven't given up the right to ***any*** privacy, just certain forms of it. In other words, just because I stroll around the park doesn't mean you get to see my bank account. :)

Comment: JoanneC: Well now, I guess that depends on whether you're strolling around the park carrying a powered-up netbook with an open WiFi connection, doesn't it. ;-)

Comment: A weakness in this argument is uncovered when we consider homeless people.  They have no private realm into which they can withdraw; they have no choice but to be in public places and thus no implicit concent can be presumed.

Comment: @fmark: That argument works only to the degree that their lack of privacy is outside their control. Sometimes it probably is, at least partially (e.g., severe emotional or psychological problems), but in other cases it's clearly not (their being homeless results from their own decisions). Somebody having chosen to be in public at all times doesn't somehow give them the extra right to limit others' free speech.

Comment: This is not true in Japan. Even in public you are not legally allowed to take pictures of people without their permission. That law is certainly not enforced for crowds like taking a picture of a train station with hundreds of people around but it is the law in Japan.

Comment: There are also data protection considerations. Also various countries require film and TV makers to get releases under certain circumstances in order to use identifiable footage of people in public: commonly they have to blur out any associates of the person they're "really" reporting on, even if the associates themselves aren't sub judice. Probably many other considerations around the world. But they don't detract from the point, it just means the law doesn't necessarily agree with the *ethical* position advanced here as being that held by the photographer. Especially outside the US.

Answer (score 25):

A photograph is no more its subject than a descriptive paragraph would be. It has no depth, no shape, just a one dimensional recording of light.

In practice, the situation you've describe is legal because to make it illegal would be absolutely ridiculous. Should authors pay royalties for describing landmarks? What if someone builds a model of a train station, from drawings, should they pay the artist or the architect? Who should a news station pay to show a warehouse burning, the building's owner, or the arsonist who started the fire?

You could also approach this from this angle: Anybody can do it, because everybody can do it. We're all free to photograph and profit from public spaces. Again, it's because we profit from the work we've created, not the object itself.

All that said, there are more restrictions being implemented every day on our right to create art based on physical spaces. Many locations require location releases - a sort of model release for a specific space. Lots of people photography requires model releases, as people have something called "likeness rights". There are waivers for those rights when reporting news, that's why you don't need a model release to photograph the President making a state visit, but you need one to use his photo to sell a product. Art photography doesn't fall into news usage, and many photographers shooting street portraits will travel with an assistant who takes care of the model releases as needed. Laws vary by country though, in Poland you can use a photo with 3 or more people in it without any kind of release.

Historically speaking, photographers haven't had to rebuff these arguments because the insane sort of intelectual property entitlement that currently exists in the western world is an brand new invention that's only gotten this... out of hand in the past 20-30 years. Artists have always ripped each off since the beginning of man's creativity. Many artists (especially painters and sculptors) were incredibly secretive about their techniques, the current sharing of knowledge we're accustomed to just didn't exist. More than a few secret recipes for pigments have been taken to the grave.

Comment: +1 for "Anybody can do it, because everybody can do it. We're all free to photograph and profit from public spaces."

Comment: @Sean While I liked the overall message of Jędrek's answer, and upvoted it, I'm not so sure that particular argument works. Say I were to borrow my neighbor's "bicycle" (his personality rights), and go on a joyride for my personal amusement and profit, and upon returning he accosted me about it -- I couldn't very well say to him, "Well, you can borrow _my_ bike any time you want", could I? Isn't that part of the fundamental nature of property rights  -- that we are allowed to refuse arrangements that someone else might see as more than fair?

Comment: @Billare - Setting aside for a moment the differences in physical vs. intellectual property and under what circumstances the later can be considered stolen... I liked the quoted text as a rebuttal to a potential 'fallacy of composition' argument. Namely, that for some behavior to be considered sustainable and beneficial in a society, its claimed positive effects must hold even when that activity is engaged in by all members, not just a few. **While this is not a complete philosophical justification in and of itself, it is a critical element that must be present for any fair justification.**

Comment: Public spaces are not private objects (as per your example Billare). We all profit from sidewalks, parks, roads and sewage systems even if we don't pay for them in any direct way (ex. having underground pipes keeps us from having to look at, smell and navigate around water and sewage trucks).

Answer (score 11):

A photo is not the object, but a representation of the object. It is, in fact, the photographer's, as artist or creator, interpretation of that object, that object at a point of time, or the moment.

Try your question, substituting the word "painting" and see if you still have the same question.  Would you argue that Monet's painting of the bridge should not sell for millions because the bridge is in a now public park?

Comment: So I suppose my _Trafalgar Square_ example wasn't a good one -- one might argue that public property gives everyone an implicit license to profit from it, as long as one doesn't exclude another. But I don't see how this addresses the _papparazzo_ example, where the "object" has agency; one's legal name isn't literally the person, but one still has tangible rights over it, to sue over things like slander and libel. Indeed, people have many representations of themselves protected by law, such as their online identities, credit card information, etc.

Comment: It is still a representation and interpretation of a person at a moment in time, and thus a creation of the artist more than the person being photographed.

Comment: @Kendall Helmstetter Gelner I still don't get it.  You have a photograph.  I create a digital representation, a copy of your photograph, at a single moment in time, in my high resolution scanner.  I blow up 2x, tint it blue, for use on the box of some software I'm selling.  It's not the work, exactly, but an interpretation.   I don't pay the original creator of the work.   Now, I'm only a naif in photography, but I don't think a single photographer here would condone that course of action.  Photographers obviously don't see their photos as ordinary "objects" in the sense cmason is describing.

Comment: An exact duplicate is not artistic because there is no change, no input from yourself whatsoever in presentation.  Put it on an easel, at an angle, in specific lighting - then you have added something and the same argument applies.  The line is when you add elements together to make an image.

Comment: This is the correct answer imho!

Answer (score 5):

When public property is photographed it actually benefits the public property, since there are taxes on the equipment purchases, image sales, and profits of the photographer. Therefore, there actually are "hidden royalties" already being paid by the photographer in the form of taxes.

Comment: To be a little US-centric for a second, what good are the taxes going to support our National Parks if the parks aren't photographed and/or visited? And if they are photographed then won't that bring in more visitors and hence fees, and decrease the tax burden a little (or make the resources go further)?

Answer (score 2):

If a person unobtrusively photographs of a public statue, monument, building, or other such work, such action will not materially interfere with any benefit anyone else might hope to receive from that work.  If there are people who would like to have photographs of the monument, and none are available for sale, someone who takes such photographs and offers them for sale at an acceptable price would be profiting by providing a service to the purchasers--a service which other people might have been able to provide, but which nobody was providing.

If one person is selling pictures of the monument when another decides to take his own pictures and sell those, the second person's entry into the market may reduce the profit available to the first person, but unless the first person has some unique right to sell pictures without competition, the second person would have just as much right to take and sell pictures as the first.  As more people enter the market, the profit available to each will diminish, but the reduction in profits will encourage current and prospective participants to seek out new markets that are less well served.