# Can you sell a photo of a hotel building or a sign of a public market?

Tags: digital, legal, selling

I have two photos that I took while on vacation, one of the Public Market sign in Seattle and the other is the Sax hotel in Chicago. I have manipulated them in photoshop and am impressed with both photos. Is it legal for me to sell these photos?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you find out if a building falls under trademark rules?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/how-can-you-find-out-if-a-building-falls-under-trademark-rules)

Comment: Also take a look at [Has there ever been a ruling on the necessity / legality of a property release for non-trademarked property?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10601/has-there-ever-been-a-ruling-on-the-necessity-legality-of-a-property-release-f)

Answer (score 1):

To try and answer the question succinctly: yes you can *sell* the photos, because you have copyright, but they may not be *publishable* depending on who buys them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can sell the photographs to whoever wants to buy them.

The problems are encountered when the images are used commercially in some design material or in an advertisment.If the building design is trademarked, such as the Sydney Opera House the buyer must be aware that it cannot be used commercially.

There is a lot of information on the [iStock Photo website](http://www.istockphoto.com/help/sell-stock/training-manuals/photography/legal-requirements-art-architecture-performances) about what can be sold.

Comment: Is that a legal requirement, or iStockphoto avoiding even potential trouble?

Comment: It is a legal requirement. The same would apply if I took a photograph of just a tattoo, without being in any context, the trademark would lie with the tattoo artist (if s/he trademarked it), in the same way taking a photo of a building the Trademark belongs to the architect (as long as they have trademarked it) copyright has different rules and a photograph of something that has been copyrighted is different. If something has been trademarked you cannot use it commercially without permission, and that includes selling a photograph of the trademark.

Comment: iStockphoto suggests that _any_ building which charges admission is off limits. I was under the impression that very few buildings are actually trademarked. Which is true?

Comment: For that matter, is that actually true of trademarks, if you're not using the image in the category of business in which it is a trademark and would not create customer confusion? Many common consumer goods are trademarked, and we don't generally worry about their appearance in a photograph. _Should_ we worry?

Comment: If the trademarked subject is the sole subject of the photograph, then you should worry, if it is a logo on a t-shirt being worn by a model then no, dont worry,in general images, however if you want to use that image for commercial reasons, a kid wearing a Nike top for example than that image cannot be used. 

The admission thing isnt really true, as St Pauls Cathedral chanrges admission however the building is copyright free and trademark free, and a photograph of that building can be used and sold. If you search for cathedral on iStock you will find a lots and i'm sure most charge admission.

Comment: here is the search for St pauls Cathedral on iStock, note that most images do not carry the edetorial useage only mark http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/st%20pauls/source/basic#138986dc and here you will see that it costs an adult £14.50 http://www.stpauls.co.uk/Visits-Events/Sightseeing-Times-Prices it seems they do not follow their own rules on this one.