# Right to use a photo taken at a Russian train station

Tags: legal, copyright, photographers-rights

I took a cool photo whilst standing on the platform of Paveletsky station in Moscow. Its a bit like [this](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Paveletskiy+vokzal/@55.72741,37.6415879,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s102068299!2e1!3e10!6s%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fstatic.panoramio.com%2Fphotos%2Fsmall%2F102068299.jpg!7i8000!8i6000!4m5!1m2!2m1!1smoscow+train+station!3m1!1s0x46b54b1f110e6ec3:0x82b6700ecd58cb70!6m1!1e1) one.

Do I have the right to use my photo on the cover of a book that I'm publishing?

Comment: If you're not sure, you should really check with a lawyer, not the Internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What legal restrictions to photography are there in European countries?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/what-legal-restrictions-to-photography-are-there-in-european-countries)

Comment: [Do they have a copyright law in Russia?](http://blog.tanyakhovanova.com/2011/10/plagiarism/)

Comment: Close... http://engl.mosmetro.ru/pages/page_0.php?id_page=587

Comment: One question that _could_ be applicable for publication in the U.S.: Are any people in the picture identifiable?

Comment: No they're not. People dressed in black with black hats on.

Comment: In the US I think (not a lawyer) this would be OK since it is a public place where the people in the picture *do not have the expectation of privacy*.  How this works in Russia, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Russian regulations do not allow the use of images of any railway structure for commercial purposes, without permission from Russian Railways.

Answer (score 4):

To confirm, you should ask for permission to make photos of Russian railroad. Here is [web](http://press.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5118) page with information about this (in Russian). Unfortunately I do not find this page in English on the web site. But here is (bad) translation from Russian
Procedure for television, video, film and photo opportunities at the facilities of OAO "Russian Railways"

> Application Form. Application for filming directed natural or legal
>   person in Corporate Communications Department JSC "Russian Railways".
>   The application shall be issued on the letterhead, signed by its head
>   and stamped by the organization
>
> For a foreign media, the application shall be accompanied by a copy of
>   the card special correspondent of a foreign media, issued by the
>   Ministry of Foreign Affairs. If the application is submitted by a
>   foreign person or entity who does not have the accreditation of the
>   Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Russian Federation, that it be
>   accompanied by copies of passports and visas for all participants in
>   the shooting.
>
> The content of the application. It shall specify the objectives and
>   tasks of the shooting, a short scenario plan and location shooting,
>   the subject, the date and time of shooting, the composition of the
>   crew, surname, first name and phone number of the responsible person.

P.S. Sorry, do not have time to translate it (and moreover my English is broken :) )